# Send a putExtra to an activity

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, android-activity

I have this code:

Rechercher.java:

```
public void doOnResult(String json){
    if ( json.equals("Aucune propostion pour le mois")||json.equals("Aucune propostion pour cette date")) {
        Toast.makeText(Rechercher.this, "Aucune proposition actuellement.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    } else {
        Intent iAfficher = new Intent(this, Afficher.class);
        extras.putString("json", json);
        extras.putInt("nbplaces", mCounter);
        iAfficher.putExtras(extras);
        this.startActivityForResult(iAfficher, 10);
    }                   
}
```

Afficher.java:

```
Integer places = extras.getInt("nbplaces");

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.afficher);
    ListView lvTrajets = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvTrajets);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    .......

    proposition.put("Date",propId);
    proposition.put("Trajet", propLieu+" de "+propVille+" --> "+propGare+" Places : "+places);
```

The places variable is always equal to 0.

I don't know why I can't get the right value.

Comment: put `Integer places = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("nbplaces");` after `setContentView`

Comment: it should be `getString` and `getInt`

Comment: @user3507621 can you see my answer

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Yeah, I get it on this activity! But it isn't my final wish, I have to pass it to another activity again, I test it and I tell you

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I get the value on the other activity, thanks a lot :) But you didn't told me this in an answer, so I can't accept your answer, I'll accept someone else answer

Comment: @user3507621 Check out my answer it will help you.

Comment: @user3507621 I think more old answer is mine below :)

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar Most Correct answers gets first priority not old.

Comment: @user3507621 also change Integer to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value from the `Bundle` in your `Afficher.java` file in your `onCreate` method as below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.afficher);
    ListView lvTrajets = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvTrajets);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    Integer places = bundle.getInt("nbplaces"); //get value here
    String jsonval=bundle.getString("json");
```

Comment: Your answer works fine, I'll accept it as soon as I can, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I think more old asnwer is mine but , the thing is your issue is solving , it is good to see it, see you next question on stackoverflow  :)

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar All the best. :)

Answer (score 1):

Move this `Integer places = extras.getInt("nbplaces");` inside `onCreate`. Also initialization of `extras`.

```
public Intent getIntent ()

Added in API level 1
Return the intent that started this activity.
```

Instead of `Integer places` use `int places`. `int` is a primitive data type so use `int` instead of `Integer` for primitive data types.

```
int places;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.afficher);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
places = extras.getInt("nbplaces");
```

You need to wait till the activity is created then use `getIntent()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getInt(java.lang.String)

```
public int getInt (String key)

Added in API level 1
Returns the value associated with the given key, or 0 if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key.

Parameters
key a String
Returns
an int value
```

Comment: `extras` is nowhere defined.

Comment: @SachinG now you can see extras declared. still don't know why its downvoted. If not declared it won't compile at all in the first place forget getting 0

Comment: Yes. It won't compile in first place. That will give compilation error right ? So using `extras` before definition is not correct. You assumed it to be declared somewhere in code that is not mentioned. If OP don't have it defined then that will give an error.

Comment: @SachinG but if you look at the question he says he gets the value 0. So it compiles fine. so it must have been declared and the assumption is right

Answer (score 1):

try this please:

```
Integer places ;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.afficher);

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); 
places = bundle.getInt("nbplaces")
...........
```

Comment: what is `extras` in your code? you need initialize that

Comment: Why have two `bundle` holding same data from intent? `b` and `bundle` both are same.

Answer (score 1):

put the following line after the bundle declaration inside onCreate() method

```
 Integer places = bundle.getInt("nbplaces");
```

and remove the following line

```
Integer places = extras.getInt("nbplaces");
```